# Windows ThreadPool API and multiple DB queries

Tags: c++, database, threadpool

I have a method (from a third party lib)

```
    bool READ_DB(Connection* con, long value);

    void TAMLTradeProcessor::CreateThreads() {
    long    nThreads = 15; // we can configure this

    // set up and run the threads
    HANDLE*                 pWaitHandles = new HANDLE[nThreads];
    CThreadInfoData*        pTid = new CThreadInfoData[nThreads];
    UINT                    nRunningThreads = 0;
    long                    lSharedIndex = -1;  

    // Initialise data blocks
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
    {
        pTid[i].m_bRunning = true;
        pTid[i].m_pnCurrentIndexPosition = &lSharedIndex;   // common index
        pTid[i].m_pDbConn = new CDatabaseConnection();
        pTid[i].m_hThread = (HANDLE )_beginthreadex(NULL,0,ThreadCB,&pTid[i],0,&pTid[i].m_nThreadId);
    ...
    }
```

It reads data off the database using the connection I pass in and matching the query for that specific value.
I have a huge list of values so I created multiple threads that retrieves values off the list and call the method, in other word I am retrieving the data in parallel using mutiple DB connection.
ThreadCB will call READ_DB.
At the moment I have created the threads myself and I have created 15 of them...just a casual number.
Is there a better way of doing this using  Windows ThreadPool API?
In other words if I need to run the same DB query over and over gain for different values (but I can only use one value at time) what is the best approach?

Comment: 15 is a terribly random number.  Actual throughput is throttled by the network bandwidth and the willingness and ability of the dbase server to run that many queries at the same time.  This usually gets you a visit from a pretty pissed-off dbase admin.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I reduced my threads just to save a trip to the dba. How would you choose this random number then? Newbie to multithreading